# Customize Material UI ToolTip maxWidth using props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

Hi so I saw in React Tooltip component documentation the option to customize the width of a tooltip
as follows

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip, { TooltipProps, tooltipClasses } from '@mui/material/Tooltip';


const CustomWidthTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    maxWidth: 500,
  },
});

const longText = `
Aliquam eget finibus ante, non facilisis lectus. Sed vitae dignissim est, vel aliquam tellus.
Praesent non nunc mollis, fermentum neque at, semper arcu.
Nullam eget est sed sem iaculis gravida eget vitae justo.
`;

export default function VariableWidth() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomWidthTooltip title={longText}>
        <Button sx={{ m: 1 }}>Custom Width [500px]</Button>
      </CustomWidthTooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was trying to see if there is any way to not hardcode the value 500 and making the maxwidth value more generic.(And maybe other fields later on)

I tried to do something like this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip, { TooltipProps, tooltipClasses } from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

const CustomWidthTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} classes={{ popper: className }} />
))({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    maxWidth: (porps) => props.maxWidth,
  },
});

const longText = `
Aliquam eget finibus ante, non facilisis lectus. Sed vitae dignissim est, vel aliquam tellus.
Praesent non nunc mollis, fermentum neque at, semper arcu.
Nullam eget est sed sem iaculis gravida eget vitae justo.
`;

export default function VariableWidth() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomWidthTooltip maxWidth={150} title={longText}>
        <Button sx={{ m: 1 }}>Custom Width</Button>
      </CustomWidthTooltip>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I haven't manage to make it work...
I would appreciate some help with this
Thank you